# python telegram bot start a conversation when a button is clicked

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a bot where I have a menu with buttons. When a button is clicked I send some data accordingly. If the selected menu has sub menu I update the buttons.

At some options (buttons) I need user's location so I need to start a conversation.
In all examples I came upon, a conversation starts when a commend is executed (for example `/start`).

**How can I start a conversation when a button is clicked?** I added an example code gathered from `python-telegram-bot`'s [examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples) to be close to my original code since I created `class`es to encapsulate the operations and generate buttons from a json file.

example:

```
import logging

from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler,
)

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

GENDER, PHOTO, LOCATION, BIO = range(4)


def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Hello", callback_data='1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Good bye", callback_data='2'),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Where are you", callback_data='3')],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()
    if query.data == "1":
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"Hello bro how are you?")
    elif query.data == "2":
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"Can't you stay? I feel lonely.")
    elif query.data == "3":
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"Start Conersation here")
    else:
        query.edit_message_text(text=f"WTF")


def ask(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    reply_keyboard = [['Boy', 'Girl', 'Other']]

    update.message.reply_text(
        'Hi! My name is Professor Bot. I will hold a conversation with you. '
        'Send /cancel to stop talking to me.\n\n'
        'Are you a boy or a girl?',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
            reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder='Boy or Girl?'
        ),
    )

    return GENDER


def gender(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Gender of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'I see! Please send me a photo of yourself, '
        'so I know what you look like, or send /skip if you don\'t want to.',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(),
    )

    return PHOTO


def photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    photo_file = update.message.photo[-1].get_file()
    photo_file.download('user_photo.jpg')
    logger.info("Photo of %s: %s", user.first_name, 'user_photo.jpg')
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Gorgeous! Now, send me your location please, or send /skip if you don\'t want to.'
    )

    return LOCATION


def skip_photo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a photo.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'I bet you look great! Now, send me your location please, or send /skip.'
    )

    return LOCATION


def location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    user_location = update.message.location
    logger.info(
        "Location of %s: %f / %f", user.first_name, user_location.latitude, user_location.longitude
    )
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Maybe I can visit you sometime! At last, tell me something about yourself.'
    )

    return BIO


def skip_location(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s did not send a location.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'You seem a bit paranoid! At last, tell me something about yourself.'
    )

    return BIO


def bio(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Bio of %s: %s", user.first_name, update.message.text)
    update.message.reply_text('Thank you! I hope we can talk again some day.')

    return ConversationHandler.END


def cancel(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("User %s canceled the conversation.", user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text(
        'Bye! I hope we can talk again some day.', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    )

    return ConversationHandler.END


def main() -> None:

    updater = Updater("token")

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('ask', ask)],
        states={
            GENDER: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Boy|Girl|Other)$'), gender)],
            PHOTO: [MessageHandler(Filters.photo, photo), CommandHandler('skip', skip_photo)],
            LOCATION: [
                MessageHandler(Filters.location, location),
                CommandHandler('skip', skip_location),
            ],
            BIO: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, bio)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
    )

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With this code user can initiate conversation by `/ask` and display button menu by `/start`.
How can I start the conversation when button defined as `InlineKeyboardButton("Where are you", callback_data='3')` is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `CallbackQueryHandler` is entry point for the conversation.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`